# Función BuscarV de Excel con R

Tags: r, excel

Quiero asociar solamente la columna de *Sexo* del **Dataframe1** al **Dataframe2** mediante la coincidencia de una columna en común denominada *ID* en ambos dataframes.

He estado buscando pero todo lo que he encontrado de código es para asociar todo el **Dataframe1** al **Dataframe2** mediante la coincidencia de la columna *ID* en común en ambos, mientras que yo solo quiero asociar la referente al *Sexo*.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de  los datos del Dataframe1 y Dataframe2? así podremos darte una respuesta concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando funciones de tidyverse puedes seleccionar las columnas de interes y realizar

```
DF <- Dataframe1 %>%
  select(ID, sexo) %>%
  left_join(Dataframe2, by = "ID")
```

Depende de la tabla de salida que necesites puedes hacer el left joint al Dataframe2

Comment: Es justamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias :)